# Asymptotic normality in linear mixed-effects models

Tags: mixed-model, references, asymptotics

Estimates for the fixed effects in a mixed-effects model are known to be asymptotically normal in distribution (under mild assumptions).

Are there any results that quantify the deviation from normality (in general, in simple cases, or just simulation studies)?